# Stitching non-R scripts with knitr, say .py

Tags: python, r, knitr

is it possible to stitch a python script using `stitch()` with knitr?

I want to produce a simple document by typing:

```
stitch('someScript.py')
```

analogous to:

```
stitch('someScript.R')
```

Answer (score 0):

As I probably have answered you on Twitter, you can try

```
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(engine = 'python')
stitch('script.py')
```

But note the Python support in **knitr** is very limited at the moment. You may or may not be satisfied by it.